# Replace char inside Intent data

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

How can I replace (setting it permanently) a single char inside the data of an Intent?

The content of the Intent is in the form of DATA:VALUE.

```
    String test = getIntent().getData().toString();
    test = test.replaceFirst("a", "b");
    getIntent().setData(???); // how can I do this?
```

Comment: What do you mean by "setting it permanently" ? Give us more details. You're not new on SO. You should know how to ask a better question than this...

Comment: _"a single char inside the data of an Intent"_ of what? DATA or VALUE?

Comment: Can you show the data:value of intent?

Comment: I want to modify a char inside the VALUE string.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you have a `data:value` can't you just update the value and push it again?

Comment: I've edited my question, hope is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want to do this?

```
String test = getIntent().getData().toString();
test = test.replaceFirst("a", "b");
getIntent().setData(Uri.parse(test));
```